# Erro de bibliotecas java em projeto

Tags: java, jsf, mvc

As bibliotecas do meu projeto não estão importando as classes do *util e outras várias também, não sei o que está havendo, pois quando crio um projeto novo essas classes e bibliotecas funcionam. Abaixo um print do erro.

Ja tentei dar Clean no projeto inteiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vai em propriedades-> java--> jre---> e adiciona a JDK que o problema sera resolvido.

Comment: valeu amigo consegui resolver

Comment: Por gentileza poste a sua reposta como resposta, ao invés de comentário

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está relacionado a importação do jdk, faça isso em:

```
Properties (do seu projeto) > Java Build Path > Libraries e informe o caminho do seu jdk.
```